# Difference between TaskQueue and MapReduce in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, hadoop, mapreduce, task-queue

I have read the docs about `taskqueue` and push queues in `gae` which is used to create long running tasks.

I have doubt in why there was the need for `MapReduce`? As both do the processing in background, what are the main principal differences between them.

Can someone please explain this?

Edit: I guess i was comparing Apples with monkeys! Hadoop, mapreduce are related. And gae is a backend framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused with two entirely different things altogether.

`MapReduce` paradigm is all about *distributed* *parallel* **processing** of very huge amount of data.

`TaskQueue` is a **Scheduler**; which can schedule a *task* to execute say **at certain time**. It is just a scheduler like a unix `cronjobs`.

Please take note of bold and italic words in above statements to see the difference.

From the definition of [TaskQueue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/)

> Task queues let applications perform work, called tasks,
>   asynchronously **outside of a user request**. If an app needs to execute
>   work in the background, it adds tasks to task queues. The tasks are
>   executed later, by worker services.

By definition, `TaskQueue` **work outside of a user request**; means there is no actual user request to perform a `task` (it is simply submitted/scheduled sometime in past). `mapreduce` programs are submitted by users to execute, though you may use `TaskQueue` to **schedule** one in future.

You are probably getting confused due to words like `task`, `queue`, `scheduling` used in `mapreduce` world. But those all thing in `mapreduce` may have some similarity, as they are generic terms - but they are definitely not the same.